# Connection problems with AC600 (aka A6100) Netgear wifi dongle

Tags: wireless, netgear

Downloaded and compiled the rtl8812AU driver for this dual-band wifi dongle. The speed is awesome...the only problem is that 50% of the time it will not connect on boot.  But 100% of the time when this happens, I can disable / enable wireless and then it always connects.  So, this is in the nature of a nuisance problem...but I'd like to connect on boot if possible.

Any ideas?

Wifi troubleshooting script output is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15167280/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your file `/etc/network/interfaces` is malformed. It may be the reason that the internal device doesn't work correctly. In any event, I suggest that you correct it. From a terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

If you do not wish to use the internal device, I suggest you blacklist its driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwl3945"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us know if connectivity has improved.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  This seems to have improved it...it connects reliably on a reboot...but I still had the problem on a cold boot.  This time though, while the network icon was "spinning", I noticed that conky displayed the wifi network name and frequency, but  not an IP address...I toggled the wifi off and on and it connected immediately.

Comment: If, on a cold start, you do: `sudo service network-manager restart` does it connect? If so, perhaps we can run a script during boot.

Comment: Seems like that is working, three consecutive cold boots with no problems.  Thanks for all your help.